# Div / Text not centering with margin:auto

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a @media query, everything is working fine, except id like to have text become centered with margin:auto when the @media query is called. I have tried soooo many things. I originally had float:left in #masterhead #header-text{} but I have changed that to display:inline-block; (I have read that, that was a solution for many). I have tried explicitly setting widths.. and display:block;

```
<div id="masterhead">
    <div id="header-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header-text">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">
                    <h3>Thin Title</h3>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="~/Content/images/stacked.png" /></a>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


#masterhead #header-text{
display:inline-block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#masterhead h1{
margin-top:0;   
font-weight: 600;
}

#masterhead h3{
padding-top:15px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #masterhead #header-text { margin:auto; }
    #masterhead h1 {font-size:30px; margin:auto;}
    #masterhead h3 {font-size:20px; margin:auto;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `h1` and `h3` elements are block level elements by default. This means that they will take up 100% of the width and so `margin:auto;` has no effect. You could change their display property or set explicit widths, but it would be easier to use `text-align: center;` and `width: 100%;` on the container/wrapping element instead.

So for example:

```
#masterhead #header-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#masterhead #header-text{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#masterhead h1{
margin-top:0;   
font-weight: 600;
}

#masterhead h3{
padding-top:15px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #masterhead #header-text { width: 100%; text-align: center;}
    #masterhead h1 {font-size:30px; }
    #masterhead h3 {font-size:20px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="masterhead">
    <div id="header-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header-text">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">
                    <h3>Thin Title</h3>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="~/Content/images/stacked.png" /></a>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this article](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) for some more handy centering tips.

---

**Edit:**

To answer your comment... even if you do not want your text to be centered, you can still use `text-align: center;` on an inline-block wrapper div as long as you  reset it back to `text-align: left;` for the children.

For example:

```css
#masterhead #header-text {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#masterhead h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#masterhead h3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#masterhead br {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #masterhead #header-text {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #masterhead #header-text a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #masterhead h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  #masterhead h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="masterhead">
  <div id="header-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="header-text">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <h3>Thin Title</h3>
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="~/Content/images/stacked.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you have to remove `float: left;` for this to work. If your goal is to float the text next to the logo, then you'll most likely have to do the centering on the parent `.container` div.

Comment: so what if I wanted to use float:left for #masterhead #header-text instead of display:inline-block? and what if I dont want to use text-align: center, but I want the text container centered.

Answer (score 2):

You should make `#header-text` to `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block` because `inline-block` covers full width.

And give width to `#header-text`.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj8x5nL7/)**

**Or**

If you don't want to give fixed width then give `text-align:center` to parent div.

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj8x5nL7/1/)**